# can we trust feature importance of a poor model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, importance

Usually when training ensemble learning algorithms or a regression model we calculate feature importance and make conclusion that feature with highest feature importance has largest affect on y-variable.

No doubt when model itself if reliable(High MSE or accuracy) however what if model is not performing well? Can we still trust feature importance?

Comment: You can trust it as much as you trust the predictive accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key consideration is that feature importance is always an importance *for the particular model* and the particular dataset. There is no such a thing as global importance. If you use different feature selection algorithms, [you can expect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231623/features-selection-why-does-boruta-confirms-all-my-features-as-important/231630#231630) that they would pick different features, hence consider different features to be important.

So if you have a poorly performing model, than feature importance tells you that the feature is important for the model when it makes its (poor) predictions. It *doesn't* mean that there is no other, better performing model, that possibly assigns less or more importance to the feature.

Comment: Thanks! Is there reference that proves your statement?

Comment: @haneulkim you have results of an experiment in the linked thread, for importance in general, it is calculated using some model, so it cannot be independent of the underlying model.